# How do I draw lines in an image?

Tags: c#, wpf

There is such a script ( it draws a triangle at given coordinates and it inserts it into the image) -

```
int[] xPoints = new int[] { Convert.ToInt32(AX), Convert.ToInt32(BX), Convert.ToInt32(CX) };      
int[] yPoints = new int[] { Convert.ToInt32(AY), Convert.ToInt32(BY), Convert.ToInt32(CY) };

int xMin = 0;
int yMin = 0;
if(xPoints.Min() < 0)
{
    xMin = xPoints.Min();
}
if(yPoints.Min() < 0)
{
    yMin = yPoints.Min();
}

int height = (yPoints.Max() + (-yMin)) * 100;
int width = (xPoints.Max() + (-xMin)) * 100;//I set the boundaries and increase the size of the image (that would not be 6x3 pixels)

Image myImage = new Image();

DrawingVisual drawingVisual = new DrawingVisual();
DrawingContext drawingContext = drawingVisual.RenderOpen();
drawingContext.DrawLine(new Pen(Brushes.Green, 1), new Point(CX, CY  ), new Point(BX  , BY  ));
drawingContext.DrawLine(new Pen(Brushes.Black, 1), new Point(CX, CY  ), new Point(AX  , AY  ));
drawingContext.DrawLine(new Pen(Brushes.Red, 1), new Point(AX * 300, AY * 300), new Point(BX * 300, BY * 300));


drawingContext.Close();

RenderTargetBitmap bmp = new RenderTargetBitmap(width, height, 100, 100, PixelFormats.Pbgra32);
bmp.Render(drawingVisual);
myImage.Source = bmp;

MainCanvas.Children.Add(myImage);

using (FileStream stream = new FileStream("Sample.png", FileMode.Create))
{
    PngBitmapEncoder encoder = new PngBitmapEncoder();
    encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(bmp));
    encoder.Save(stream);
}
```

I draw lines and that's what it turns out -

[image: problem triangle]

Why does this happen? What is it necessary to multiply x, y (when creating a Point) so that the triangle fits exactly into its boundaries? And it will be universal, that is, if I change the coordinates, everything will also work fine. Also, the CB line is not drawn. I suspect that due to the fact that it is on the border of the image. If I make the unlimited size of the brush (2000), then this line will occupy the entire image, and if less, it is not drawn at all.

Comment: `There is such a script` Implies you have copied it from somewhere and no idea how it works....

Comment: @Eser You are not right